# WebClient returns (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, webclient

I have a problem with my WPF application, which is returning
"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error" in my call back function.

I have the following code;

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetProduct DownloadStringAsync ");
try
{
     GetProduct.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CATCH GetProduct DownloadStringAsync " + ee.Message);
}
```

And in my callback method:

```
private void GetProductCallBack(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Error != null)
  {
   . . .
```

e.Error = "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error"

Is it a Server access problem or something's wrong with my code?
Concerning the URI, it has been tested, and is ok.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Your callback method is strange. Why do you override error description?

Comment: Its not complete, just to show you that I get the error at the very beginning..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a client-side problem, but a server problem. Check this for more info: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html

> This error can only be resolved by fixes to the Web server software.
>   It is not a client-side problem. It is up to the operators of the Web
>   server site to locate and analyse the logs which should give further
>   information about the error.

Comment: Oh! that's kind of relieving.. I'll try refer this to the admin. thanks. btw, why couldn't the error id not be specific for each type of error.. I googled around and got all sort of error referred to as the Error (500)!

Comment: Error 500 is basically the "catch all" error response. It's basically saying "I don't know how or why, but something went wrong.".